# simple udp client boost

Tags: c++, udp, boost-asio, netcat

I am trying to write a simple client to publish a UDP message to a server. My buffer is not being sent as a udp.  When I try and send the message to netcat it does not appear.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
boost::asio::io_service io_service;
boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint endpoint_(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string("0.0.0.0"), 2399);
boost::asio::ip::udp::socket socket(io_service, endpoint_);
boost::asio::socket_base::broadcast option(true);
socket.set_option(option);
char*  data = "hello";
socket.send_to(boost::asio::buffer(data, strlen(data)), endpoint_);
getchar();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you bind a socket to ip `0.0.0.0` that means, that it will listen on all available interfaces. I don't know, if this works in conjunction with a broadcast. May you start smaller, by binding it to `127.0.0.1` and try the broadcast. If that fails too, try to send to the endpoint of netcat. This way you can isolate your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binding the socket to an endpoint is a server function. You could notice this by the fact you may receive a "Bind error/Address already in use" error if something listens on that port already.

Instead use `socket.open`:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8ba27ca268b60cff)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

int main()
{
    using namespace boost::asio;
    using ip::udp;
    io_service io_service;

    udp::socket socket(io_service);
    socket.open(udp::v4());
    socket.set_option(socket_base::broadcast(true));

    const char* data = "hello";
    udp::endpoint endpoint_(ip::address::from_string("0.0.0.0"), 2399);
    socket.send_to(boost::asio::buffer(data, strlen(data)), endpoint_);
}
```